# Appointment.Bind() and Mailbox

Tags: exchangewebservices

I retrieve an appointment by its unique ID. Now I want to find out which mailbox it is in.

I tried using appointment.Organizer, but this does not work for meetings, or for normal appointments - since appointments can be moved around between mailboxes, the Organizer can be different from the user that has the appointment in his calendar.

Is there a function to get a folder, given only an appointment and an ExchangeService?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the SMTP address of the mailbox associated with a particular EWSId one way that should work is using convertId to convert the EWSId to a StoreId and just use generic mailbox address in the Mailbox field then the results you get back (if that ID is good) should contain the Mailbox its associated with eg

```
            String EWSId = "AQMkADY4ZDQ4M2UyLTRhYjItNDhkYy1hMG...";
        AlternateId aiRequest = new AlternateId();
        aiRequest.UniqueId = EWSId;
        aiRequest.Mailbox = "user@mailbox.com";
        aiRequest.Format = IdFormat.EwsId;

        AlternateId aiResultsStore  = (AlternateId)service.ConvertId(aiRequest, IdFormat.StoreId);
        Console.WriteLine(aiResultsStore.Mailbox);
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: `        aiRequest.Mailbox = "user@mailbox.com";` - seems I need to enter the value I want to obtain in the first place. :(

Comment: No you enter like this it should be an address that isn't resolvable in your org (eg user@mailbox.com should work fine). Give it a try and let us know if it doesn't work. If you want know an application that does it this way look at the EWSeditor http://ewseditor.codeplex.com/