# Exchange EWS Java Push Notifications with Shared Calendar or Contact folders

Tags: push-notification, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have set up Push Notifications and they work wonderfully more or less. But events do not fire on a calendar/contacts folder that is shared FROM (eg you are not the owner of) someone else. This makes sense to me, the event occurred "somewhere else".

However, is there a way to receive these notifications, other than logging into each of the owners mailboxes and setting up separate subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Subscriptions can't traverse Mailbox boundaries so you will need to create a separate subscription for each Mailbox you want to listen for events from. If they are shared calendars you should have rights to create Subscriptions on those folder the only issue you may have is if you have a large number of Folders you will exceed the throttle setting for Max Subscriptions. If its a Service application you could use EWS Impersonation to get around that.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks glen! In this case this wont work. Impersonation is a nono. This is an individual end user app. It looks like its also impossible to fetch the owner's mailbox from the folder?

Comment: Do you just want to know the SMTP Address of the Mailbox owner give a particular Folder id ? if that's the case you should be able to use CovertId see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742434/appointment-bind-and-mailbox